# Get url of featured image after wp_insert _post function

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

I have a problem in getting url of featured image post. I've created a function with wp_insert post to post data and set featured image for them. everything works fine except displaying the url of featured image. here is my code :

```
$newpostname=$movie['title'];
global $wpdb;
$id_ofpost_name = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = '$newpostname'");
$id_ofpost_title = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '$newpostname'");
if ($id_ofpost_name || $id_ofpost_title) {echo 'post Exist';} 
else {
// Register Post Data
$post = array();
$post['post_status']   = 'publish';
$post['post_type']     = 'post'; // can be a CPT too
$post['post_title']    = $newpostname;
$post['post_content']  = '';
$post['post_author']   = 1;

// Create Post
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );
// Add Featured Image to Post
$image_url  = $movie['urlPoster'];
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); // Set upload folder
$image_data = file_get_contents($image_url); // Get image data
$filename   = basename($image_url); // Create image file name
// Check folder permission and define file location
if( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
    $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
} else {
    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
}
// Create the image  file on the server
file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );
// Check image file type
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );

// Set attachment data
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
    'post_content'   => '',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
);

// Create the attachment
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );

// Include image.php
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

// Define attachment metadata
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );

// Assign metadata to attachment
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

// And finally assign featured image to post
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
}
```

post inserting works perfect .the problem is i want to get the url of featured image after wp_insert_post and featured image uploaded.

any clues ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the attachment ID, so you can simply use [`wp_get_attachment_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link):

```
$featured_image_uri = wp_get_attachment_link( $attach_id );
```